# absolute fastest lookup in python / cython

Tags: python, c, performance, optimization, cython

I'd like to do a lookup mapping 32bit integer => 32bit integer.

The input keys aren't necessary contiguous nor cover 2^32 -1 (nor do I want this in-memory to consume that much space!).

The use case is for a poker evaluator, so doing a lookup must be as fast as possible. Perfect hashing would be nice, but that might be a bit out of scope.

I feel like the answer is some kind of cython solution, but I'm not sure about the underpinnings of cython and if it really does any good with Python's `dict()` type. Of course a flat array with just a simple offset jump would be super fast, but then I'm allocating `2^32 - 1` places in memory for the table, which I don't want.

Any tips / strategies? Absolute speed with minimal memory footprint is the goal.

Comment: "Absolute speed with minimal memory": you do know that there is not an optimal choice here, yes? It requires a satisficing engineering trade-off that yields (by definition) one or two sub-optimal choices. If [Ignacio's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24857860/282912) is too memory intensive then module `sqlite3` is probably your best simple alternative.

Comment: Do you know how many entries your mapping will have, and are you willing to sacrifice initial creation time to make lookups faster?

Comment: Also, what does "absolute speed" mean to you?  Total CPU cycles consumed over the entire lifetime of the table (including creation time), or just the cycles spent doing lookups?

Comment: @NickBastin: initial creation time is not an issue, only time done doing lookups. the table could have 133 million entries at most.

Comment: If your bottleneck is going to be `int`→`int` mappings, you should use PyPy and use the standard PyPy `dict`. [PyPy is so absurdly fast for this use-case it isn't even funny.](https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/d25148faf20669589993)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should actually define what "fast enough" means to you, before you do anything else.  You can always make something faster, so you need to set a target so you don't go insane.  It is perfectly reasonable for this target to be dual-headed - say something like "Mapping lookups must execute in these parameters (min/max/mean), and when/if we hit those numbers we're willing to spend X more development hours to optimize even further, but then we'll stop."

Second, the very first thing you should do to make this faster is to copy the code in `Objects/dictobject.c` in the Cpython source tree (make something new like `intdict.c` or something) and then modify it so that the keys are not python objects.  Chasing after a better hash function will not likely be a good use of your time for integers, but eliminating `INCREF/DECREF` and `PyObject_RichCompareBool` calls for your keys will be a huge win.  Since you're not deleting keys you could also elide any checks for dummy values (which exist to preserve the collision traversal for deleted entries), although it's possible that you'll get most of that win for free simply by having better branch prediction for your new object.

Comment: Do you mean the `cython` source? at `https://github.com/cython/cython`? I can't seem to find the `Objects/dictobject.c` file there, even with search...

Comment: The "cpython" source - the source code for python itself (the C implementation).  You can start with the default `dict` object and just tweak it to make it faster.

Answer (score 6):

You aren't smart enough to write something faster than `dict`. Don't feel bad; 99.99999% of the people on the planet aren't. Use a `dict`.

Comment: if it helps, the key space once initialized is completely static - no insertions needed.

Comment: Doesn't change a thing.

Comment: It's really not that hard to write something faster than the standard `dict` for many very specific use cases - even to the point of just taking the dict implementation itself and optimizing it and exposing it as a new object.  `dict` is fantastic and reasonably optimal for the general use case, but that means there are tradeoffs that punish almost every specific use (possibly with the exception of general string hashing, which `dict` is very good at).

Answer (score 4):

You are describing a perfect use case for a hash indexed collection. You are also describing a perfect scenario for the strategy of write it first, optimise it second.

So start with the Python `dict`. It's fast and it absolutely will do the job you need.

Then benchmark it. Figure out how fast it needs to go, and how near you are. Then 3 choices.

1. It's fast enough. You're done.
2. It's nearly fast enough, say within about a factor of two. Write your own hash indexing, paying attention to the hash function and the collision strategy.
3. It's much too slow. You're dead. There is nothing simple that will give you a 10x or 100x improvement. At least you didn't waste any time on a better hash index.